# preview of a pdf format file in a popup model in next.js without downloading the pdf file

Tags: next.js13, next.js14

trying to preview the pdf file in preview popup model without downloading the image file are previewing but pdf file with react pdf viewer getting errors.

when I click the preview button in preview popup I should get that pdf to be viewed without downloading